# Prevent code from being executed at the same time (Create resized image)

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking, image-resizing

I'm developing a httpHandler for serving my webapplication with resized images. If the requested image and specified sixe doesn't exist I'll create that image.

The problem is if two (or more) requests reach the server at the same time and asks for a image that must be created. How can I prevent this from happening? How can I lock the code under the time it takes for the first request to create the image? When the image is created the second (and following) request will get the created image from filesystem.

Thanx!

// Nicke

Comment: Search MSDN for the `lock` keyword or read up on `Synchronisation primitives`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the C# simple locking mechanism. Create a static object that is shared to all threads (perhaps use a singleton to wrap this operation) and use [double checked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) locking:

```
if (!pictureExists)
{
    lock (_syncRoot) // This is the shared object to lock by
    {
        if (!pictureExists) // double checked
        {
            // create it
        }
    }
}
```